# How to use Exists method for the property of the list object

Tags: c#

There is a list of Employee (`List<Employee>`) and it contains objects of Employee  and each Employee having Different property. One of the property is Employee Id. I want to add employee into list if that employee doesn't exists in the list and I want to check it through employee id using `List<T>.Exists(Predicate<T>)` method. How can I check the current employee id exists in the employee list or not. I got stuck here. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Please do keep in mind that if your number of employee is large you will end up searching the list each time you add a new employee. It might be better to add the employee to a dictionary collection with employee id as key

Comment: It represents a method that contains a set of criteria and checks whether the passed parameter meets those criteria or not. A predicate delegate methods must take one input parameter and return a boolean - true or false.

Comment: Please read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like that `if (!yourList.Any(x => x.Id == Id))`

Do not forget about `using System.Linq;`

edit.

`if (!yourList.Exists(x => x.Id == Id)`

Comment: Yes, I think the question was mostly a "What is a Predicate<T> and how do I get/pass one", so I tried approaching it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..But i only have to use exists method

Comment: @shivani It should be the same, but with ``Exists`` instead of ``Any`` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.exists?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

A predicate is a method that returns yes/no, true or false.
A predicate of T is a method that takes a an argument of T (and returns true or false).

`employees.Exists(e => e.Id == theId)`

would be passing an anonymous function as a predicate. You could also pass a normal method. If you have a method

bool EmployeeIdIsSeventeen(Employee e) {
  return e.Id == 17;
}

then you can call `employees.Exists(EmployeeIdIsSeventeen)` just as well.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't helpful. What did you do, what do you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: ..it works and it is very helpful also.Actually I made  a silly mistake thats why it doesn't work that time.